# Convert a NFA to Regular Expression

Tags: regex, nfa

I found a same question on this website, and the answer was a [PDF describing how to convert an NFA to a regex](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2009/lectures/lect_08.pdf). But this is not working because this method has some conditions:

1. There are transitions going from the initial state to all other states, and there are no
   transitions into the initial state.
2. There is a single accept state that has only transitions coming into it (and no outgoing
   transitions).
3. The accept state is distinct from the initial state.
4. Except for the initial and accepting states, all other states are connected to all other
   states via a transition. In particular, each state has a transition to itself.

And in my example the start state is just going to the next state but not to all states (e.g q0 goes to q1 but not to q2, q3), and there are transitions into the start state.

So what is the easiest way to convert an NFA to regex? I am not giving an NFA example becuase I don't have a spesific one, is just a general question, because I come across with this kind of DFA where the start state is not connected with all the states, and the are transitions into the start state.

I want a general algorithm to convert this kind of NFAs.

Comment: This conversion algorithm is described in the book of Automata of Ullman

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is assuming those conditions, because any NFA can be modified to fit those requirements.

For any kind of NFA, you can add a new initial state q<sub>0</sub> that has an epsilon-transition to the original initial state, and also using an additional transition symbol called ∅ (they call it empty set symbol, assumed to be a symbol which does not match any symbol from the original NFA) from it to any other states, then use this new state as the new initial state. Note that this does not change the language accepted by the original NFA. This would make your NFA satisfies the first condition.

For any kind of NFA, you can add a new acceptance state q<sub>a</sub> that has an epsilon-transition from all acceptance state in the original NFA. Then mark this as the only acceptance state. Note that this does not change the language accepted by the original NFA. This would make your NFA satisfies the second condition.

By the above construction, by setting q<sub>0</sub> != q<sub>a</sub>, it satisfies the third condition.

And in the link you provided, the fourth condition is explained by having a special transition symbol called ∅ (the empty set symbol) for which no actual alphabet from original NFA can match. So you can add transitions with this new symbol from every state to any other state. Note that this does not change the language accepted by the original NFA.

So now the NFA has been modified to satisfies the four requirements, you can apply the algorithm there to convert the NFA into Regular Expression, which would accept the same language as the original NFA.

*Edit to answer further question*:

To answer your question in the comment, consider the NFA with two states, q<sub>A</sub> and q<sub>B</sub>. q<sub>A</sub> is the initial state as well as the only acceptance state. We have a transition from q<sub>A</sub> to itself with symbol 0,1. We also have transition from q<sub>A</sub> to q<sub>B</sub> with symbol 1. Lastly we have transition from q<sub>B</sub> to q<sub>A</sub> with symbol 0.

Visualization:

```
 0,1    
  |  1
->qA----->qB
  ^       |
  |-------|
     0
```

Step 2. When we normalize the NFA, just put the new init state (q<sub>init</sub>) that points to q<sub>A</sub>, and put a new acceptance state (q<sub>acc</sub>) from q<sub>A</sub>.

Step 3. We want to remove q<sub>A</sub>. So q<sub>A</sub> is the q<sub>rip</sub> in the algorithm (in page 3). Now we need to consider every states that enters q<sub>A</sub> and every states that exits from q<sub>A</sub>. In this case, there are two states pointing to q<sub>A</sub>, that are q<sub>init</sub> and q<sub>B</sub>. There are two states that are pointed to by q<sub>A</sub>, that are q<sub>B</sub> and q<sub>acc</sub>. By the algorithm, we replace the transitions q<sub>in</sub>->q<sub>rip</sub>->q<sub>out</sub> with a transition q<sub>in</sub>->q<sub>out</sub>, having the transition symbol R<sub>dir</sub>+R<sub>in</sub>(R<sub>rip</sub>)*R<sub>out</sub>, where:

1. R<sub>dir</sub> is the original transition from q<sub>in</sub> to q<sub>out</sub>
2. R<sub>in</sub> is the original transition from q<sub>in</sub> to q<sub>rip</sub>
3. R<sub>rip</sub> is the original loop at q<sub>rip</sub>
4. R<sub>out</sub> is the original transition from q<sub>rip</sub> to q<sub>out</sub>

So in this case we replace the transition q<sub>init</sub>->q<sub>A</sub>->q<sub>B</sub> with q<sub>init</sub>->q<sub>B</sub> with transition symbol (0+1)*1. Continuing this process, we will create in total 4 new transitions:

1. q<sub>init</sub>->q<sub>B</sub>: (0+1)*1
2. q<sub>init</sub>->q<sub>acc</sub>: (0+1)*
3. q<sub>B</sub>->q<sub>B</sub>: 0(0+1)*1
4. q<sub>B</sub>->q<sub>acc</sub>: 0(0+1)*

Then we can remove q<sub>A</sub>.

Step 4. We want to remove q<sub>B</sub>. Again, we identify the q<sub>in</sub> and q<sub>out</sub>. There is only one state coming to q<sub>B</sub> here, which is q<sub>init</sub>, and there is only one state departing from q<sub>B</sub>, which is q<sub>acc</sub>. So we have:

1. R<sub>dir</sub> = (0+1)*
2. R<sub>in</sub> = (0+1)*1
3. R<sub>rip</sub> = 0(0+1)*1
4. R<sub>out</sub> = 0(0+1)*

So the new transition q<sub>init</sub>->q<sub>acc</sub> will be:

> R<sub>dir</sub>+R<sub>in</sub>(R<sub>rip</sub>)*R<sub>out</sub>
>
> (0+1)* + (0+1)*1 (0(0+1)*1)* 0(0+1)*

And we can remove q<sub>B</sub>.

Step 5. Since every state in the original NFA has been removed, we are done. So the final regex is shown above.

Note that the final regex might not be optimal (and in most cases it won't be optimal), this is expected from the algorithm. Finding the shortest regex for an NFA (or even DFA) in general is very difficult (although for this example it's easy to see that the first component already covers all possible strings)

For completeness, the shortest regex accepting the same language will be:

> (0+1)*

Comment: Nice thank you fore the nice reply. On the site i provide, on 2.1 Example: From GNFA to regex in 8 easy figures the first step removes the state A, but this state on the example has no looping transition on the state A, what about if my A state has looping transitions over? I have to put this transition to the q0 (new initial state)? Moreover, what about if a state sends, data to the old initial state?

Comment: For instance, if the original initial state qA, has looping arrows with 0s and 1s, sends to qB 1 and receives from qB 0 how this will looks like? for looping arrow will be (0+1)* and for send and receive (01)* ? and both sent from the NEW initial state to qB with one transition like (0+1)*(01)*?